# How to open a mbtiles files with java on desktop?

Tags: java, algorithm, mbtiles

I want to make an offline desktop map app with java on windows. Until now I tried unfoldingmap(it won't open if the size of the file is more than 1 MB). I wonder how can ı make a program that open mbtiles and organized tiles make it a map.

Comment: You'll either need to find a library that can read this file type or look at the specification and write a parser yourself. If you just google it, there is a page with the spec and some implementations: https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/wiki/Implementations